# How to fix my ceiling lights?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have a bunch of ceiling lights that don't work when I replace the bulbs.

Electricians are too expensive but although I don't have experience in this area I'm willing to learn and do it myself if possible.

How can I figure out what's wrong with them and fix them myself?

Comment: Even though you think electricians are too "expensive" sometimes it's your best bet. Troubleshooting is not something that can be taught to a complete newbie IMO. You need to have a basic understanding before you can start pulling things apart. And from your description, "ceiling lights don't work", it is impossible to even begin to help you.

Do you own any meters or testers? Do you know anybody who knows about this stuff that can help you on site?

Answer (score 4):

> **How can I figure out what's wrong with them and fix them myself?**

Equip yourself with the basic tools needed. Make sure you understand the basic principles of household electricity. Make hypotheses, test those hypotheses. Act on confirmed hypotheses.

As far as I know, about 1 person a week is killed in the USA by accidental electrocution (and many times more in the construction industry). You seem a little inexperienced so I hope you'll understand that folk contributing to this website don't want to contribute to those statistics. I recommend you learn about electrical safety from someone with experience. Perhaps there are local evening courses you can attend or you know someone who is qualified and willing to teach? Fixing broken household electrical items is something that careful householders can do but it isn't something you should rush into in a state of unprepared ignorance. Think of it as akin to knowing nothing about cars but wanting to replace the brakes on the car your wife uses to take your kids to kindergarten.

Equipment wise, you might need a set of *insulated* screwdrivers and a *category-II* multimeter that can measure AC voltage.

You need to have a basic understanding of voltage and current, the purpose of fuses, circuit breakers and RCB/RCBO/GFCI devices. You should understand what live/hot, neutral and ground/earth wires are for and how they are typically connected in homes in your country or locale.

You need to understand exactly in what ways this investigation can kill you and how your attempts at repair might kill other people. You need to be really sure you know how to work safely and how to always have the system in a safe state.

Some hypotheses you could test:

1. The replacement bulbs are broken.
2. There's no electrical power reaching the bulb holder.
3. There's a fault in the switch associated with the light fitting.
4. The fuse or breaker in the main-panel has cut-off the circuit to isolate a fault.

Here's a few things you might do to test those hypotheses

1. Try swapping bulbs with ones in a room that has working lights.
2. Use a multimeter to carefully measure the voltage in the socket.
3. Turn off power at main panel, Remove the switch, examine it, swap with working switch.
4. Examine fuses and circuit-breakers for indications that they have blown or turned off.

If a fuse has blown or a circuit breaker has turned off, you need to identify the cause before replacing or resetting.

Comment: While all good suggestions, does the form of the question lead you to beleive that the OP is up to these tasks? You make clear allusions (to the initiated) about the risks and complexities, but the detailed suggestions may send a reckless novice on a fool's errand.

Comment: @bib: I sometimes find it hard to strike the right balance between writing a welcoming and encouraging answer and burying the OP in advice that may put them off this site. I take your point though and will add an early paragraph on the subject. If you still have concerns please consider writing another answer - this site probably needs more answers per question and I'd very likely upvote another answer that succeeds in addressing those concerns better than I can.

Comment: I appreciate the dichotomy of our role - guide as best we can, but don't enable risky/bad behavior. For the present OP, I would err on the side of *put the screwdriver down!*  But I realize that they may not listen, and some guidance may be better than random poking on their part. It's a tough call.